# complex numbers: $i^i $ vs $\pi $: which is larger?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am kind of novice to complex numbers, may one pls check if the following makes sense: I am to compare $i^i$ vs $\pi$ ?

What is bizarre to me is that $i^i$ is complex while pi is real, so how come that two quantities are comparable directly .. curious where is my mistake?

> $$i^i = k\text{, assume } k \in \mathbb{R}$$
>   $$\implies i\ln i = \ln k$$
>   $$i = 0 + 1i = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$$
>   $$\implies r=1, \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2} \text{ in } z = e^{i\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\text{ for polair form of } z=i$$
>   $$i^i = i\cdot \ln e^{i\dfrac{\pi}{2}}= i^2\dfrac{\pi}{2} = -\dfrac{\pi}{2} = \ln k$$
>   $$\implies e^{-\dfrac{\pi}{2}} = k = 0.20788$$
>   $$k < \pi$$

Answer (score 3):

Don't be fooled by the presence of $i$, you wouldn't say $i^2 \not\in \mathbb{R}$, right?

> What is bizarre to me is that $i^i$ is complex while $\pi$ is real, (...)

As you found with your own calculations, $i^i$ is in fact real but to get that value, you (implicitly) picked the *principle branch* of the (multi-valued) complex logarithm.

Picking that branch leads to the value $e^{-\pi/2}$, which is obviously smaller than $\pi$, but this isn't necessarily the case when picking another branch.

In general, you have:
$$i^i = e^{- \frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k} \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})$$
where the principle value corresponds to taking $k=0$.

See also: [Mathworld: Complex Exponentiation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html)

Comment: $i^i = \exp(i (\log|i| + \pi i/2 + 2\pi k i ) )$ is actually always real valued

Comment: Some values of $i^{i}$ are less than $\pi$ some are greater then $\pi$. (take $k =-10$ for example). So the question does not make sense unless  a branch of logarithm is specified.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks, I didn't even check but updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @StackTD: thx good to know how to arrive at general case solution

Comment: @bak The (complex) exponential function is periodic with period $2\pi i$, so $e^z = e^{z+2k\pi i}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

$i^i$ is not complex. It is real number. You can write it as $(e^{i\frac \pi 2})^i$. Which becomes $e^{-\pi/2}$.
As $e^x$ is increasing function, and $-\pi/2 \lt 0$
So $i^i \lt e^0 =1 \lt \pi$

Comment: Well, it *is* complex. And it is real.

Comment: You would say $i^2 $ is also complex

Comment: nice your path is much shorter )